# How do I use a PC Dance Pad with Xna?

Tags: xna, input

I have a Dance Pad and I want use it in XNA as a controller. It has a USB connection.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6):

iirc, XNA does not have support itself for non-XInput controllers. This means you'll have to use another API to access your dance pad (and you'll be limiting yourself to the PC in that case).

[Here](http://ksgamedev.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/using-non-xbox-controllers-with-xna-3-1/) is a blog post describing some options for non-360 controller support in XNA 3.1. The techniques should scale to 4.0.

Comment: There are Xbox 360 dance pad controllers, although I admit I have no idea how they show up.

Comment: @Joe Wresching Most likely as a subset of the typical Xbox gamepad.

Comment: That would make the most sense, which is why given my experience with peripherals I assume it's as far from that as possible.